# Subdomain htaccess issue in Magento

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, magento, subdomain

```
public_html/                    # www.domain.com
public_html/subdomain             # subdomain.domain.com
public_html/.htaccess
public_html/subdomain/.htaccess
```

I have a subdomain subdomain.domain.com

I have .htaccess file under public_html

This htaccess file contains this code:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com$
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdomain/
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdomain/$1
```

I need to install magento inside subdomain folder

.htaccess file inside this folder is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Magento Installed successfully, But I am facing a problem:

http://subdomain.domain.com/admin (this url works)

but when I hit http://subdomain.domain.com/index.php/admin its shows "No input file specified."

All internal URLs in admin are also throwing same error.

Please help me what wrong I put in my htaccess

Thanks in advance.

Comment: But why are you using longer URL instead of shorter one?

Comment: Since I am talking about magento, and in Magento admin section, all internal URLs use "index.php".

That's why I have posted url with index.php

Comment: Right but goal should always be to use shorter cleaner URL and that you are already getting at present. For longer one try: `http://subdomain.domain.com/index.php?admin`

Comment: This is my customer's requirement.
If mod_rewrite is "off", then add index.php in URL.

Comment: If you rename your .htaccess to something else does that longer URL work?

Comment: Then it throws "Internal Server Error".

Comment: For internal server error you need to check your Apache error.log

Comment: Apache error log is showing "RewriteRule" errors.

Comment: If you have moved out your .htaccess (OR commented the rules) then RewriteRule errors shouldn't happen. btw what error?

Comment: currently I am getting "RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters" error

Comment: That means you have syntax errors in your .htaccess